# Craft 2 JS error in CMS since upgrade to 2.7.0

Tags: control-panel, upgrades, craft2

My Control Panel has stopped working since upgrading to Craft v2.7.0. in chrome. I get the following JS error no matter what is clicked in the entry fields and no action is taken. So for example if I want to remove and image and click the minus button nothing happens. If I try and add Matrix fields nothing happens. All of these were working prior to the update.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at n.constructor.getWorkingTaskInfo (cp.js:863)
>       at n.constructor.setTaskInfo (cp.js:832)

I'm running on PHP 7.0.13 any ideas?

Comment: Also just checked it on firefox same issue.

Comment: Tried upgrading to v 2.7.2 and still throwing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling Craft. I believe there was another report from a user that had similar JS errors. Try replacing the core Craft files in `craft/app` and see if that helps.

Craft 2.7.1 was also recently released.

Comment: Probably worth trying to just clear out `craft/storage/runtime/cache` folder, too.